# Growth of groups versus Schreier graphs

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

This question is motivated by this one [What is the relation between the number syntactic congruence classes, and the number of Nerode relation classes?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32899/what-is-the-relation-between-the-number-syntactic-congruence-classes-and-the-num) where it essentially asks to compare the growth of the syntactic monoid with the growth of the minimal automaton.  A special case is the following.  Let G be an infinite finitely generated group and H a subgroup such that G acts faithfully on G/H.  How different can the growth of G and the Schreier graph of G/H be?

I know the Grigrchuk group of intermediate growth has faithful Schreier graphs of polynomial growth.

> > Are there groups of exponential growth with faithful Schreier graphs of polynomial growth?

Schreier graphs of non-elementary hyperbolic groups with respect to infinite index quasi-convex subgroups have non-amenable Schreier graphs so ths should be avoided.

Comment: Every regular graph of even degree is a Schreier graph of a free group. Basically you can make any growth you like. Faithfulness of a Schreier graph is not a problem usually. If you want a particular example in the spirit of the Grigorchuk group, you can take the Basilica group: it has exponential growth, acts faithfully on its Schreier graphs corresponding to stabilizers of infinite sequences, and these Schreier graphs have polynomial growth.  

Comment: I believed a free group was no problem but most of the examples I tried to draw in my head were not faithful. I was sure somebody new an example off the top of their head. Basilica is good because the polynomial growth is from contracting like in Grigorchuk group. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This holds true, for example, for free groups. Actually, take $G$ to be a free product of three copies of $Z/2Z$, which has an index two subgroup which is rank 2 free. The Cayley graph for this group (which has undirected edges) is just a trivalent tree, with edges colored 3 colors by the generators, so that every vertex has exactly 3 colors (this is known as a [Tait coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tait_coloring)). Any cubic graph with a Tait coloring corresponds to a Schreier graph of a (torsion-free) subgroup $H$ of $G$, which is the quotient of the Cayley graph of $G$ by the subgroup $H$ (one may choose a root vertex to correspond to the trivial coset). Closed paths starting from the root vertex correspond to elements of the subgroup $H$.

Choose a cubic graph with a Tait coloring which has linear growth and corresponds to a subgroup $H$ satisfying your condition ($G$ acts faithfully on $G/H$). This is equivalent to $\cap_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}=\{1\}$. For example, take a bi-infinite ladder, labeling the two stringers with matching sequences of colors, which then determine the colors of the rungs. By making these stringer sequences aperiodic, you can guarantee that $\cap_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}=\{1\}$. Changing the root vertex corresponds to changing the conjugacy class. In fact, we may choose stringer sequences which contain any word in $G$. Then putting a root at the endpoint of such a word, we guarantee that it is not in the corresponding conjugate subgroup of $H$.